# Mongo doesn't let NestJS create a new DB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I have a backend with NestJS, it is configured with `mongoose`. The `app.module.ts` :

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://admin:root@localhost:27017/'),
    CatsModule
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
```

If I let the URI like this it works correctly but creates a '`tests`' database. I want a custom database, so when I try to set the URI to `mongodb://admin:root@localhost:27017/my-custom-db` it cant connect...

I've tried to create `my-custom-db` manually, but it still fails

The error :

```
[Nest] 14480  - 26/06/2022, 12:28:27   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
```

Comment: in general  even possible using dashes in mongodb databases or collections names  is a bad practice: https://devops.datenkollektiv.de/why-you-shouldnt-use-a-dash-in-a-mongodb-collection-name.html

Answer (score 1):

The Problem was because `Mongoose` use a diferent format to connect to a specific database, we have to pass the name by option:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot(
    'mongodb://localhost:27017',
    {useNewUrlParser:true,user:"root",pass:"example",dbName:"nest"}),
    UserModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
```